# ERROR: Write access to repository not granted. fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

I've been encountering a recurring error while attempting to push changes to a remote repository that requires having an SSH key. I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR: Write access to the repository not granted. fatal: Could not read from the remote repository. Please ensure that you have the correct access rights and that the repository exists.
```

I made sure to add the SSH key correctly. My SSH agent is up and running (`$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)`) and the identity is correct (`ssh-add -l -E sha256`). The output of this command `ssh-add -l -E sha256` and the SSH key in my github account are matching. Also, I ran this command `git remote -v` and the urls are ok. I've also removed the urls (`git remote rm origin`) and added them again, but still no luck. When I test the SSH connection (`ssh -T git@github.com`), I get this message:

```
Hi [MYUSERNAME!] You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Everything seems to be fine, but I just can't push up my local branch.

Both git pull and git clone work without any issues. The problem only arises when I try to push changes. FYI, I can't fork the repo.

Do you have any suggestions on how to resolve this? I'm using Windows.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you sure you are permitted to push to that repo, or to that branch?

Comment: Is this a public repo?

Answer (score -1):

There are three points that you need to consider,

1. Do you have enough permission given by admin to read/write.
2. Have you completed the public key generation and updating the same in the github account.
3. Validate that your local repo is trying to push to the correct URL. Run git remote show origin and look at the "Push URL" which should, for SSH, be something like git@github.com:repo.git.

If you complete the above 3 steps then you will be able modify the content.

Comment: I already mentioned that I finished step 2.